How can I marshal a struct into JSON where one string field is streamed from an io.Reader containing raw text?
I have a structure like:
{
  Foo int `json:"foo"`
  BigString io.Reader `json:"bigString"` // I want this to be encoded as a JSON string
}

And I would like to Marshal this into JSON without having to read the entire contents of BigString into memory. This data will need to be appropriately escaped for JSON (\" etc.)
I have reviewed Encode struct object with io.Reader in a streaming manner in go, which currently suggests two possible solutions for the streaming element of this (neither are ideal, but both are acceptable). But in that question's scenario, the source stream is already JSON escaped.
I've looked into Go's JSON marshalling, and it seems the string escaping is buried in private functions.
Incidentally, my io.Reader is from a file handle which I do have access to, so if that opens up the solution space, I'd be interested.

Since io.Reader is an interface, how about implement encoding.TextUnmarshaler ?

You cannot. You have to write your one MarshalJSON for your struct.

Thanks @Volker. That sounds right. And I think the piece I was uncertain about (how do I escape raw data for a JSON string) is as simple as json.Marshal(string).
